# I am building an app and want to allow the user to navigate into a folder

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, subdirectory

The user is originally presented with a ViewController with a set of folders to choose from.  When a folder is chosen, a new view controller called FolderContentsViewController appears and should display the contents of the folder, but no contents are being displayed.  There is a collectionview in the FolderContentsViewController with cells called 'HoldGroupCell'.

This is my current code for the HoldGroupCell and the UICollectionViewDataSource for the FolderContentsViewController.  Can someone help me locate the issue?

```
class HoldGroupCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var folderURL: URL?

    let folderImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    let folderNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(folderImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(folderNameLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            folderImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            folderImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: -10),
            folderImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            folderImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            folderNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            folderNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            folderNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: folderImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            folderNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(with itemURL: URL) {
        folderNameLabel.text = itemURL.lastPathComponent
        
        if itemURL.hasDirectoryPath {
            let folderImageName = itemURL.lastPathComponent
            let folderImage = UIImage(named: folderImageName)
            folderImageView.image = folderImage ?? UIImage(named: folderImageName)
        }
    }
    
    func configureContents(of folderURL: URL) -> [HoldGroupCell] {
        guard let contents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []) else {
            return []
        }
        
        var cells: [HoldGroupCell] = []
        contents.forEach { (itemURL) in
            let itemCell = HoldGroupCell()
            itemCell.configure(with: self.folderURL!.appendingPathComponent(itemURL.lastPathComponent))
            cells.append(itemCell)
        }
        
        return cells
    }
}





extension FolderContentsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return folderContents.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HoldGroupCell", for: indexPath) as! HoldGroupCell
        let fileURL = folderContents[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        var isDir: ObjCBool = false
        fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path, isDirectory: &isDir)
        
        if isDir.boolValue {
            cell.backgroundColor = .gray
            
            let folderName = fileURL.lastPathComponent
            cell.folderNameLabel.text = folderName
            
            let folderImageName = folderName
            let folderImage = UIImage(named: folderImageName)
            cell.folderImageView.image = folderImage
            
            let cells = cell.configureContents(of: fileURL)
            cells.forEach { cell.contentView.addSubview($0) }
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: There is no SwiftUI here. This is UIKit.

Comment: Please consider turning this question into a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! It will make your question easier to answer :)

Comment: What debugging have you done? What actually happens when you run your code? Is `cellForItemAt` being called? If so, then what happens? Please note that the code you posted has many issues due to cell reuse.

Comment: @HangarRash could you identify some of these issues?  I do not believe cellForItemAt is being called, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Stoic how can I do this?

Comment: @bennykuttler You need to show how `folderContents` is populated. If it's empty then the collection view will be empty and `cellForItemAt` won't be called.

Comment: @HangarRash I defined it earlier in the viewDidLoad with the following code:         guard let folderPath = folderPath,
              let folderURL = URL(string: folderPath),
              let folderContents = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

Comment: @bennykuttler Please put all relevant details in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @bennykuttler you can make sure to only include what's really relevant to the question. For example, you don't need to include the cell background color in your question. Try deleting things, and if it doesn't affect the issue then you can remove them from the question :)